# Индикация прогресса загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как рассчитать загрузку сайта? Видел на сайтах статус загрузки сайта, знаю что у XMLHttpRequest есть событие upload.onprogress для загрузки **на сервер**:

```
XMLHttpRequest.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
  console.log( 'Загружено на сервер ' + event.loaded + ' байт из ' + event.total );
}
```

Как сделать то же самое, но для загрузки (скачивания) страницы/данных **с сервера**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

oReq.open();

// ...

// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
    // ...
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
  }
}

function transferComplete(evt) {
  console.log("The transfer is complete.");
}

function transferFailed(evt) {
  console.log("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
}

function transferCanceled(evt) {
  console.log("The transfer has been canceled by the user.");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GvdSy/

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/",
    data: {},
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // прогресс загрузки на сервер
        XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                // делать что-то...
            }
        }, false);
        // прогресс скачивания с сервера
        XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                // делать что-то...
            }
        }, false);
    },
    success: function(data){
        // делать что-то при успешном завершении...
    }
});
```